# Why does cmp(unicode, np.int64) fails with UnicodeDecodeError?

Tags: python, numpy

Why does this fail in this way:

```
import numpy as np
cmp(u"Never", np.int64(500))   #UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf4 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

while this succeeds:

```
cmp(u"Never", int(np.int64(500)))
```

I ran across this while trying to group a pandas dataframe containing mixed types.

(python 2.7)

Comment: On one hand, that's a comparison you really shouldn't be making. On the other hand, the particular kind of error you got is quite a surprise.

Comment: Super weird.  On my machine, `u'' < np.int64(383)` works and then `u'' < np.int64(384)` doesn't.

Comment: Guess this is why no one uses python2 anymore

Comment: @wim: Take a look at the *bytes* in those values: `divmod(383, 256) =  (1, 127)`, and `divmod(384, 256) = (1, 128)`.  128 is outside the range of ascii characters.

Comment: `u''.__lt__(np.int64(384))` returns `NotImplemented` giving numpy a chance to screw it up with the reflection `np.int64.__gt__`.  Presumably by attempting to coerce the scalar using `.tobytes().decode()`.

Comment: Is this up-to-date numpy, or the numpy pre-installed by OS X or the RHEL5 numpy package or something?